# Select two distinct primes each with 6 binary digits and use them to design an RSA cryptosystem.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography, euclidean-algorithm

**Describe how to design an RSA cryptosystem based on primes p = 13 and q = 7. That is, propose the public key and the private key. Encode the message 100101 and then decode it.**

I'm mimicking my professor's work but I'm getting stuck on a few parts. Was wondering if someone could help me and let me know what exactly I'm missing here.

So here is what I have:

$p = 13$ , $q = 7$

$N = p*q \implies N=(7)(13) = 91$

$(N,e) = (p-1)(q-1) = (12)(6) = 72$

I picked $e$ so that $GCD(e, (N,e)) = 1$

So I let $e = 5 \therefore GCD(5,72) = 1$

Now I use the **Extended Euclid Algorithm:**

I end up with:

a | q | y

72| . | 29

5 | 14| 2

2 | 2 | 1

1 | 2 | 0

0 |

I end up with:
$(2*1) + 0 = 2$

$(14*2) + 1 = 29$

but then I get $(5)(29) - (2)(72) = 1$ but for some reason my teacher gets $145 = 1( \mod 72)$ I don't understand where he gets the $145$ from ? Did he just say oh ok $145 - 72 = 73$ which is $73 \equiv 1 \mod 72$? Also did he mean to put $145 \equiv 1 (\mod 72)$ instead of $145 = 1 \mod 72$? I know that $5(29) = 145$ if that means anything.. I could very well be missing something very trivial here but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$145 \equiv 1 \pmod{72}$ is equivalent **by definition** to $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}\ ( 145 = 1 + 72k )$, which you have proven by finding $5 \times 29 - 2 \times 72 = 1$.

Comment: Ok, that makes a little more sense. But how exactly do we decide to pick $145$? Couldn't we also say $217 \equiv 1(\mod 72)$ because ∃k∈Z $(217=1+72k)$

Comment: @Shammy: Yes but didn't you want a multiple of $5$? $217$ isn't one.

Comment: Wow, you're right. That makes sense.

Comment: @Shammy: You're welcome. =)